# How can I check the current status of my ES6 Promise programatically?

Tags: javascript

If I `console.log` the returned promise I can see it has a primitive value [[PromiseStatus]]. But I want to use this or similar flag in my program, where I can decide if the promise is in pending state or resolved or failed.

Comment: Checking the status of a promise is an anti-pattern. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: which browser are you talking about? Firefox logs `Promise { <state>: "pending" }` on a newly created Promise ... chrome outputs `Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}`

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes browser logs, but I'm not getting the value in the program.

Comment: @torazaburo I want to show loader while the promise is in progress. But always keeping a flag inside the component which is using the promise may be a tidy task.

Comment: sorry, I was just trying to determine the browser. I realise now that what you want to do is impossible with native Promises

Comment: *I want to show loader while the promise is in progress.* If by loader you mean a progress bar or spinning wheel, then would `startProgress(); load() . then(stopProgress)` work?